# Google maps Current Location

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I have a really complicated app that has various different functions. One of these functions include a google maps tab. The app is structured in such a way that each tab is a fragment.
In this particular case I am having trouble declaring my google map object to grab my current location data.

### Here is the relevant code

```
public static class GpsClass extends Fragment{
    View rootView;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    
    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        if (rootView != null){
                ((ViewGroup) rootView.getParent()).removeView(rootView);
            }
            try{
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gps, container,false);
                mMap = ((SupportMapFragment)getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mymap)).getMap();
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                
            } catch(InflateException e){
             
            }
            return rootView;
        }
    }
```

In this codes implementation I get a Null Pointer exception when I try to declare mMap. If I remove the *getAvtivity()* call the eclipse tells me I can't make a static reference to a non-static method. If I remove the mMap lines my app works with a google map in one tab (the other tabs implement other things which all work).

Comment: why you create `getView(...)` static? in your `GpsClass`

Comment: try putting your code under onAttach

Fragments take some time to attach to activity. Till this happens, sometimes we get NullPointerException

Comment: What happens if you use it like this `mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mymap)).getMap();`???

Comment: @SimplePlan what do you mean?

Comment: To use v2 your `Fragment` needs to extend `SupportMapFragment` not `Fragment`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you include your layout xml?

If your map fragment is `SupportMapFragment`  (`com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment`), use:

`mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager ().findFragmentById (R.id.map)).getMap ();`

or

if your map fragment is `MapFragment` (`com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment`), use:

```
mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager ().findFragmentById (R.id.map)).getMap ();
```

EDIT:
The actual answer to the OP's question:
Make sure you're using the right class name for the Map Fragment when declaring it in your layout XML.

Comment: He cant make a static reference to the non-static method getSupportFragmentManager() from the type FragmentActivity..which he already told in the question..

Comment: @Ani Fichadia: you indirectly stumbled onto my solution. All I did was change my xml to match com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment. Then boom it worked. :)

Comment: @SeahawksRdaBest that was what i too told you..Why didnt you accept my answer..Please give me an upvote atleast..

Comment: @Lal `getSupportFragmentManager()` is not available because he's using a `Fragment` instead of a `FragmentActivity`, but `getFragmentManager()` is supported within a `Fragment`.

@SeahawksRdaBest: yeah, I've made the mistake of not using the right class value when declaring the Map fragment within the layout. Glad that worked for you :)

Comment: where have i said to use getSupportFragmentManager in my answer..I said to use getFragmentManager().. @AniFichadia

Comment: Slight clarification to what I said above, if you use `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()`, it is legal because `getActivity()` returns a `FragmentActivity` (where `getSupportFragmentManager()` is actually defined). 


However, within a `Fragment` `getSupportFragmentManager()` is not defined as a method, but `getFragmentManager()` is. It is perfectly fine to just use `getFragmentManager()` instead of `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()` to lookup the fragment

Comment: @Lal I didn't see your answer when I made the comment, however, you did make a comment under the OP's post "What happens if you use it like this mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) **getSupportFragmentManager()**.findFragmentById(R.id.mymap)).getMap();", which will still cause the static method error (which was what I was looking at).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
GoogleMap mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

and in your xml

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

Comment: As I mentioned in the question. I can't do that.                  Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getSupportFragmentManager() from the type FragmentActivity

Comment: your answer is almost right. However the getActivity() fuction must be called. If it is not I get the Static method error as previously mentioned. So in the end your answer is only half right.

Comment: where have i said to use getSupportFragmentManager in this answer..I said to use getFragmentManager()..

Comment: But error was not there for you..It was at the xml file no..I too said tat na..use SupportMapFragment.. @SeahawksRdaBest